# Concentration: lower bound for $\sup_u \mu(\{a + \epsilon u \mid a \in A\})$, where the sup is over unit vectors $u \in \mathbb R^n$

Tags: probability, convex-geometry, geometric-probability, concentration-of-measure, optimal-transport

Let $\mu$ be a probability distribution on  $\mathbb R^n$. For $\epsilon > 0$ and a Borell set $A \subseteq R^n$ with $\mu(A) > 0$, define the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $A$ as $A^\epsilon := \{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid dist(x,A) \le \epsilon\}$ , where $dist(x,A):= \inf_{a \in A}\|x-v\|$ is the distance of the point $x$ from the set $A$. Under certain geometric constraints (e.g $\mu$ is log-concave, etc.), one can establish an exponential bound of the form

$$
\mu(A^\epsilon) \ge 1-c_1\exp(-c_2(\epsilon-c_3)^2), \;\forall \epsilon \ge c_3,
$$

where $c_1,c_2,c_3 > 0$ are constants independent of the dimension $n$.  Thus, the neigborhood $A^\epsilon$ will eventually "fill up" the whole space. Such inequalities date back to the works of M. Talagrand (and perhaps before).

Now, for a unit vector $u \in \mathbb R^n$, define $A_\epsilon(u):= \{a + \epsilon u \mid a \in A\}$, the Minkowski sum of $A$ and the singleton $\{\epsilon u\}$, obtained by translated $A$ in the direction specified by $u$. Define

> **Question.** Can one play a similar game (of course, with analogous geometric constraints on $\mu$) to get lower bounds on $\sup_u\mu(A_\epsilon(u))$ as a function of $\epsilon$ ?

### Related question

- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325952/what-happens-to-the-gaussian-volume-of-a-borel-set-when-it-is-translated

Comment: For instance if $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, then $\mu(A^\epsilon(u))$ is independent of $\epsilon$ and u. Also, if $\mu$ is the usual Gaussian measure and $A$ is a ball centered at zero, I would strongly expect that $\mu(A^\epsilon (u))\leq \mu(A)$ always. I don't know if these measures satisfy your assumptions, though.

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes, you intuition about Gaussian case on ball is on point. In fact, this should generalize to any isotropic distribution. But, in general, even the Gaussian case is far from simple. See related question here (sorry, I forgot to include a link in the post) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325952/what-happens-to-the-gaussian-volume-of-a-borel-set-when-it-is-translated